# Where can I find a good manual for warp server?

Tags: haskell, webserver, yesod, web-development-server

I created a yesod webapp using `yesod init`. During development I used `yesod devel` to run the warp server on debug mode.  Now I've finished a preliminary version and I want to deploy it on ec2 amazon server.  So for an Apache server I could do `sudo service appache start` to start the server, and the server can keep on running after I close of the terminal.

How do I put my application on warp server and run it (production mode)?   Is there any good websites that can show a quick tutorial on this?  I've been searching for sometime but no luck, the closes ones are  [The yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics), [this blog](http://docs.yesodweb.com/blog/announcing-warp) and [haskellwiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Servers).

Comment: Can't you just statically link your application on a local machine and upload the binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/yesodweb/gJeUT3uUIkg/rcDaEtLUFVkJ) discussion board is really informative on how to run a Yesod web site on actual servers.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider following the recommendations in the [deployment chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp), or using the [Keter deployment system](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter).

Comment: I am following the set up for Nginx, but I still need to get warp running so that Nginx can redirect all tcp(port 80) traffic to it right (warp port)?

Comment: The scaffolded site includes Warp inside of it. The executable you compile already contains a fully functional web server.

Comment: Oh really ?  I though it was on warpDebug mode? So I can just run yesod devel?  Also as to the question of server shuts down after I close the terminal,  I think there is a work around where I could just run yesod in the background using the command unix command nohup.  But somehow I feel there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You don't want to use yesod devel, you want to compile a binary. And then you probably want to run it with a process monitor such as upstart. The deployment chapter has full details on such a setup.

Comment: Do I need to move Procfile to root and make package.json in-order for the binary to work? When I go directly to my dist/build/appname/appname and run it, it returns error
appname: InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: config/settings.yml"))